# NVIDIA GeForce GT525M problem with ubuntu 11.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

I have problem with nvidia in
11.10 when i setup nvidia driver gnome not work and more effects too and compiz not work ( i use laptop ,, VIDEO MEMORY : 1GB DEDICATED intel/nvidia ) please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your card dual? If so you have more trouble than you think since ubuntu does not by default support dual vga cards (nvidia optimus) at this point.

I have the gt540m and had to do quite some searching on that.

I did my searching in december, and by the time, the only option available was to download a module and run some commands, so that you kill your high end card and only work on your low end, onboard card.

You can find details on that here: http://hybrid-graphics-linux.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Acpi_call

I searched a bit now to look for your answer, and looks like there have been a few developments in the topic in the past couple of months. A team was working on a project called bumblebee, designed to help ubuntu support optimus cards, and they seem to have released it. I found [this tutorial](http://www.ivegotavirus.com/blog/2011/11/06/how-to-get-optimus-working-on-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric/) on how to use it, but this is something I have not yet used myself/have no idea if it will mess my system up or not.

Long story short, your options are A: kill your card, work with onboard one, or B: try making your system compatible.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: acpi_call is deprecated because you won't survive suspend through it, i.e. the card stays on after suspend. Bumblebee as of version 3.0 provides excellent support for toggling the power on the discete card. See also http://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969

Comment: please assist me here. I have the gt540m. do you think this could work? http://www.ivegotavirus.com/blog/2012/01/23/installing-bumblebee-3-0-tumbleweed-on-ubuntu/#more-865. I plan on trying it on my system.

Comment: I guess so. The most reliable installation instructions can be found at http://bumblebee-project.org/install.html#Ubuntu (or the AU question that I've linked above)